# Why is the data-dump generation not (more or less) fully automated?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is the January 2011 data-dump incomplete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75101/why-is-the-january-2011-data-dump-incomplete)

The recent announcement of the [Creative Commons Data Dump Jan ’11](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/creative-commons-data-dump-jan-11/) includes a shift to a bi-monthly release cycle (unfortunately):

> Because the dumps are quite a bit of
> work for us, we’re moving to a
> bi-monthly schedule instead of
> monthly. Meaning, you can expect dumps to
> every two months instead of every
> month.

I'm a bit surprised that generating the dumps apparently amounts to *quite a bit of work*: given the impressive agility of the Stack Exchange team regarding almost daily releases of the engine across a whole network of sites, I wonder why generating the data-dump isn't more or less a fully automated process, including some tests to prevent obvious bugs (see [Why is the January 2011 data-dump incomplete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75101/why-is-the-january-2011-data-dump-incomplete))?

Comment: And according to [Re-Launching Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/re-launching-stack-exchange-data-explorer/): *The life cycle of a data dump [...] Now that we migrated to servers we control, the process is almost simple — all we do is select a bunch of data from export views (containing public data) and insert them into a fresh DB. We are not stuck coordinating work between 4 machines across 3 different geographical locations.* But maybe that only applies to [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com) and not to the downloadable dumps?

Comment: @Arjan - Good additional information regarding the subject matter indeed, thanks! Since Jeff suggested to _use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, which will continue to be updated monthly_ in his post, it seems to apply to http://data.stackexchange.com/ only, though it is not quite understandable (at least without further insights, hence the question), why there should be a major difference between both use cases regarding respective process automation possibilities.

Comment: Let me play devil's advocate here but considering that the data is torrented, it would take a while to get seeders in place to get it distributed in a timely manner.  That process cannot (shouldn't?) be automated.  I know I'd like some control over the torrents I'd be seeding, I imagine members of the team would feel the same way too unless there was a dedicated seed (which I have my doubts at the moment).

Comment: @Jeff - you're probably right concerning the final distribution/deployment at ClearBits, however, I'm rather asking with topic 2 of the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) in mind, i.e. a _one click build process_ to generate the archive(s), ideally running some integrity tests thereafter to catch obvious bugs like the mentioned [missing files](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75101) at least.