# Why is the data-dump still 'quite a bit of work', despite being (more or less) fully automated?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Due to a (meanwhile fixed) [bug concerning the January 2011 data-dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75101/why-is-the-january-2011-data-dump-incomplete), I've recently asked [Why is the data-dump generation not (more or less) fully automated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/why-is-the-data-dump-generation-not-more-or-less-fully-automated). The question has been closed as a duplicate by Geoff, since [his very welcome answer explaining the cause of the bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75101/why-is-the-january-2011-data-dump-incomplete/75128#75128) implied, that there is indeed an automation process in place already.

However, Geoff didn't answer my (implied) sub question, why generating the dumps apparently still amounts to *quite a bit of work* regardless, resulting in the unfortunate shift to a bi-monthly dump schedule.

Could you please elaborate on that? Maybe this work could be delegated to the community in case?

I realize, that providing a data-dump monthly had been an [arbitrary choice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) - still a monthly dump cycle is a pretty obvious choice regarding common use cases as well (think e.g. archiving, data analysis etc.) and I'd therefore very much prefer, if it could stay that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the data-dump still 'quite a
>   bit of work', despite being (more or
>   less) fully automated?

For one it requires a 3.5 gig upload, which takes forever and sometimes fails. The increased size means the export is slower.

Overall it when doing a data-dump you are stuck context switching multiple times a day, a 1 minute interruption 5-6 times in a day can pretty much kill hours of productivity.

http://data.stackexchange.com is updated monthly, in general people still have access to the same level of data they used to.