# Why are data dumps bi-monthly now?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is the data-dump still 'quite a bit of work', despite being (more or less) fully automated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75641/why-is-the-data-dump-still-quite-a-bit-of-work-despite-being-more-or-less-fu)

[This post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/creative-commons-data-dump-jan-11/#comments) says it takes a bit of work to create the dumps. It seems to me most of the work can be automated. Not sure what is the "bit of work" that takes two months to finish instead of one.

[This meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/why-is-the-data-dump-generation-not-more-or-less-fully-automated) has a similar inquiry. Yet it was closed because 'supposedly' it was a duplicate. The other post was about why the torrent was incomplete. It wasn't about why creating the dump takes too much work. I don't see how it was a duplicate!

The whole issue has gaps in providing adequate explanations & information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a matter of the "bit of work" taking two months rather than one.  Even if it only takes two hours, that's two hours of work that they only feel the need to do once every two months now instead of every month.

As the first linked post says, if you need more up-to-date data, use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), which will continue to be updated monthly.

Comment: Does it provide full dumps?