# November 2010 Datadump - SODDI import does not create table

Tags: support, data-dump

I used SODDI to import the november datadump into mysql, and noticed the posthistory table isn't created in the database. Any ideas why?

Comment: I guess, I just changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `posthistory.xml` file was new for the November 2010 data dump, and it's possible that the SODDI tool doesn't even know to look for it.

I looked at the published code for SODDI and it does not, in fact, know anything about the `posthistory.xml` file. But it's open source, so feel free to fix it! (And while you're doing that, download the latest January 2011 data dump.)

Comment: I tried fixing SODDI, but no success so far. I posted my question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750612/importing-so-datadump-in-mysql-error

Answer (score 3):

Giving you the benefit of the doubt: November 2011 has not occurred yet. If you automated an import of its data dump, it's reasonable that you'd get empty tables.

Was that actually a typo, and this is a problem with the November 2010 data dump? If so, you may be encountering [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75101/why-is-the-january-2011-data-dump-incomplete), which has since been fixed; try re-downloading the data dump.

EDIT:
Hmm, okay. Have you seen [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45333/fast-multi-platform-data-dump-import-sql-server-2000-2005-2008-sqlite-mysql/69956#69956) regarding how Nov. 2010 affected SODDI? It's not clear whether the developer completed the updates.

Comment: Yes that was a typo, and this is a problem with the November 2010 data dump. I don't think its the same bug because all the xml files are present and they aren't empty. So the tables should be created (that is assuming SODDI works correctly with the new format)

Comment: By 'new format' I meant the format of the data dump which was changed: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-10/